# Append to CSV File

Tags: powershell, csv, append

I am trying to create a program that processes a number of csv files. I have created an output file that has the first csv file added with headers. Now I am trying to append the next file to it.

This is the first line of the $AFw file:

```
"08-01-2023 09:00:00","08-02-2023 09:00:00","1","DAYTONA","104.5","1045","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
```

I have the following code to do the append:

```
    $Append = Import-Csv $AF
    $AppendNew = Import-Csv $AFw 

    # Append contents of source CSV to destination CSV
    $Append1 = $Append + $AppendNew

    # Export the updated data to the destination CSV file
    $Append1 | Export-Csv -Path $AF -NoTypeInformation
```

The input file will need a number of blank columns (87) then the last field.
The last line of the first file and the first and second line of the appended file are below.

```
"12/31/2023 09:00:00","01-01-2024 00:00:00","BRANDY BRANCH","9990000","26,138.0","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","10.451000"
,,,,,,"1",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,"1",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

When I run the program through the debugger it appears to be correct in the AppendNew variable just before I append it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What unexpected behaviour are you seeing? And what is your *expected* behaviour instead?

Comment: The first line of the $AFw file is an example of what should be appended to the file $AF. I am just getting all of the commas in the appended file. I hope that is more clear. Thanks.

Comment: File `$AFw` appears to have no _headers_. Does `$AF`?

Comment: That is correct. $AFw does not and $AF does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're trying to append CSV data from one file to another without needing any in-memory transformations, you can simply perform a ***plain-text* file operation**.

The command below makes the following **assumptions**:

- **File `$AFw` must have the *same column structure* as file `$AF`, but *must not have a header row*** (an initial line with column names).
- Both [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) and [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content) must correctly detect the character encoding of your files; if not, pass an `-Encoding` argument as needed.
- The file paths must not contain `[` and `]` characters, as the (positionally implied) `-Path` parameter of these cmdlets would interpret those as [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) metacharacters; if they do, use `-LiteralPath $AFw` and `-LiteralPath $AF` instead of just `$AFw` and `$AF`.

```bash
Get-Content $AFw | Add-Content $AF
```

---

**Performance improvements**:

- The above is simple, but relatively slow.
- **If your `$AFW` file fits into memory *as a whole*** - and assuming that the newline formats of your files are either the same or that ending with a mix of CRLF and LF isn't a problem - you can **greatly speed up the operation with `Get-Content`'s `-Raw` switch**:

```bash
# Much faster than the above, but reads $AFw file *as a whole*.
# -NoNewLine prevents Add-Content from appending an extra newline.
Get-Content -Raw $AFw | Add-Content -NoNewLine $AF
```

- If the **file is *too large* to fit into memory as a whole** and the first command above (`Get-Content` *without* `-Raw`, which reads the file *line by line*) is too slow, you have two options:

  - Use **`Get-Content`'s `-ReadCount` parameter to read *blocks* of lines at a time**; the larger the line count, the faster the command, but also the larger the memory consumption.

    ```bash
    $count = 100000 # example: how many lines to read at a time
    Get-Content -ReadCount $count $AFw | Add-Content $AF
    ```
  - Use **.NET APIs** directly, which is significantly more complex, however:

    - For technical reasons, you must always pass *full* file paths to .NET methods, which is what [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) ensures.
    - Unlike *Windows PowerShell*, .NET uses (BOM-less) UTF-8 as the default character encoding (as [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) now does too), so explicit character encodings may need to be passed as additional arguments.

      ```bash
       [System.IO.File]::AppendAllLines(
         (Convert-Path $AF),
         [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path $AFw))
       )
      ```

Answer (score 0):

`Import-Csv` takes the first line of your file as the header line, unless `-Header` is specified.

Also, using a `List` might be more efficient

try this:

```
$CsvCollection = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
$CsvCollection.add((Import-Csv $AF -Header the,names, of, all, the, fields <#skip -Header if there a header in the file #> ))
$CsvCollection.add((Import-Csv $AFw -Header the,names, of, all, the, fields <#skip -Header if there a header in the file #> ))
$CsvCollection | Export-Csv -Path $AF -NoTypeInformation
```